# iPhone, Missing outlet tableView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm rewriting some old cold in my new project and I'm sure I've come across this before, but I can't find the problem.

I can't seem to find a tableView outlet, with the lower case t it looks like its specified in code. But it could be using a reserved keyword and I have to use an option in the Ib to use it.

Just not sure how to get hold of it ?

Heres the old project, with tableView

[image]

Heres my new project

[image]

```
h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class OverlayViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {

    NSMutableArray *listOfItems;
    NSMutableArray *copyListOfItems;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
    BOOL searching;
    BOOL letUserSelectRow;

    OverlayViewController *ovController;
}

- (void) searchTableView;
- (void) doneSearching_Clicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Can you show the code in the .h file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your object's class in Interface Builder set to UITableViewController like it is in the code?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CodeIntegration/CodeIntegration.html.  List item 4 shows you a picture of the inspector where you can set the class for your object.